# "Royals" vs "Royalties": Which is the correct usage?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, nouns

Two different headlines below and I would like to know which is the correct use of the word here:

1. "**Royalties** draw line in the sand on Islam"
2. "**Royals** draw line in the sand on Islam"

Below is the link to the actual news headline and also a Facebook post that triggered my curiosity. Thank you in advance.

source: https://www.malaysiakini.com/news/398560

source: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10211989548948061&set=a.2262622319047.2124240.1053139405&type=3&theater

Comment: I vote that this question is off topic and should be closed.

Comment: #2 Is correct.  Royals are people of royal birth or status.  Royalty refers to such people for example "Royalty attended the society wedding" or "Several royals attended the society wedding".   Royalty also means payment for the use of an original work.  Royalties, however, mean only payments for the use of original work.

Comment: @ab2 yes I know that "royalties" can also mean payment but let's ignore that. I have seen the usage of the word "royalties" used before to denote the royals. (For example in this link: http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=9B05E4DB163BE733A25755C0A96E9C946097D6CF&legacy=true )

Comment: I ask this because the word "royalties" used in the headline above sounds better than say using the word "royals". And a few dictionaries provide the plural form of royalty as "royalties".

Comment: Other examples of the use of the word royalties are "the richest royalties", "the most powerful royalties", "behave like royalties".

Comment: Fabio, no matter what you have seen in a dictionary and regardless of the examples you just cited, "royalties" in the plural is used to mean one thing only, payment for the use of an original work.  In your examples, the singular "royalty" would be correct, even when describing many people (much like the singular furniture can describe every piece of furniture in a house.)

Comment: Possibly a variant of English used in the Middle East uses royalties to mean several members of royalty (or several royals), but even if so, that use would be local.  I couldn't read your NYT link, but it was an obituary, which means it was not written by NYT staff, but provided by the family.  If you find an article in the Guardian referring to royalties attending a state dinner given by the Queen, I will withdraw my comment. :)

Comment: @Steven Littman Thank you. though i agree the standard use of "royalties" means a form of payment, I still believe that in can also refer to the royal family (esp those that have authority and power as a monarch).

Comment: @ab2 how about these examples, here's a few just by googling: 

"Personal attacks on royalties (including the Queen Mother) are conducted with a venom that suggests underlying frivolity"

source: https://www.theguardian.com/observer/comment/story/0,,348626,00.html

"All the family, foreign Royalties, special Ambassadors & Envoys were invited"

source: https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2012/feb/23/queen-victoria-faberge-notebook

Comment: "What other ceremonial could have brought together a vast concourse of this kind with its admixture of foreign royalties"

source: https://www.theguardian.com/news/1953/jun/03/mainsection.fromthearchive

Comment: @ab2 also the NYT obituary should have been proof read by their editors before publishing and it had this to say "The Dowager Empress was one of the richest royalties in Europe, being worth several million dollars."

Comment: OK.  I asked for quotes from the Guardian and you provided them.  There are also a few quotes from the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168256?redirectedFrom=royalties#eid): (1)a1592   R. Greene Frier Bacon (1594) sig. F   I came to haue your royalties to dine With Frier Bacon heere in Brazennose; (2)  1761   H. Walpole Let. 25 Sept. (1857) III. 441   The late Royalties went to the Haymarket, when it was the fashion to frequent the other opera in Lincoln's-inn-fields.  continued..

Comment: continued  1813   Lady Burghersh Lett. (1893) 51   They are just like the Windsor Royalties, for they literally know every thing.

1885   H. R. Haggard King Solomon's Mines xvi. 269   This long line of departed royalties (there were twenty-seven of them). 1902   W. B. Yeats Let. 13 June (1994) III. 207   I will neither mix myself up with English royalties nor ‘English Soldiers & Sailors’ with whom the Princess as you say, ‘is so much interested.’

1952   G. Vidal Judgm. of Paris i. 15   He had felt like a royalty when the man from the Excelsior picked him up.   continued...

Comment: 2nd continuation  1998   E. Denby Grand Hotels 213/2   European royalties and statesmen from America were hotel guests at the time of the funeral of Emperor Meiji in 1912.   So it is OK to use royalties to refer to several royal personages, but if you want to know what sounds better and more natural, it is "royals" -- definitely in the US.

Comment: @ab2 Those are great examples. and makes me believe stronger in using the word "royalties" to refer to the royals (however very uncommon). Thank you.

Comment: Fabio, the Guardian quote is from 1953; the NY Times obituary is from 1901.  You can rest assured that in NY, royalties in the plural means payment and nothing else; the word for members of the Queen's family is royals.  I am not an expert in British usage, but I'd bet it's pretty much the same there in 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much to my surprise, I found examples of ***royalties*** used to refer to royal personages in the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168256?redirectedFrom=royalties#eid).  Non-subscribers will hit a pay wall on this link, and the entire entry for royalty and royalties is too long to quote, but here are all the examples of **royalties** meaning royal personages:

> a1592   R. Greene Frier Bacon (1594) sig. F   I came to haue your
>   royalties to dine With Frier Bacon heere in Brazennose
>
> 1761   H. Walpole Let. 25 Sept. (1857) III. 441   The late Royalties
>   went to the Haymarket, when it was the fashion to frequent the other
>   opera in Lincoln's-inn-fields.
>
> 1813   Lady Burghersh Lett. (1893) 51   They are just like the Windsor
>   Royalties, for they literally know every thing.
>
> 1885   H. R. Haggard King Solomon's Mines xvi. 269   This long line of
>   departed royalties (there were twenty-seven of them).
>
> 1902   W. B. Yeats Let. 13 June (1994) III. 207   I will neither mix
>   myself up with English royalties nor ‘English Soldiers & Sailors’ with
>   whom the Princess as you say, ‘is so much interested.’
>
> 1952   G. Vidal Judgm. of Paris i. 15   He had felt like a royalty
>   when the man from the Excelsior picked him up.
>
> 1998   E. Denby Grand Hotels 213/2   European royalties and statesmen
>   from America were hotel guests at the time of the funeral of Emperor
>   Meiji in 1912

The OED (link above) also gives other meanings of **royalties**; the one of most interest here is (I quote only three examples):

> d. In pl. Emblems or insignia of sovereignty. Also fig. Cf. regalia
>   n.1 2a. Obs.
>
> 1607   R. C. tr. H. Estienne World of Wonders 122   This iolly Iupiter
>   clothed in his royalties.
>
> 1769   O. Goldsmith Rom. Hist. I. 39   He assumed a crown of gold..and
>   robes of purple. It was perhaps the splendor of these royalties that
>   first raised the envy of the late king's sons.
>
> 1863   H. E. Manning Serm. vii. 266   The Vicar of Christ was clothed
>   with his Royalties

Thus the OP is correct that both sentences in his question are correct.  As to which sounds better, to a native English speaker in the US, **royals** not only sounds better, but **royalties** sounds incorrect.  A speaker of British English might differ, given the quotes supplied by the OP from *The Guardian*.

It remains now only for someone to find **royalties** used in *People Magazine* for me to unconditionally raise the white flag.  Well, maybe not.  *People* is not the best example of English usage.